# Unique key and replace statement

Tags: mysql

I am getting problem while adding multiple rows at the same time
I have a mysql table in which Replace multiple rows of the same id

Suppose I have 2 columns
1) offer_id
2)categories
By using php script I am replacing all the rows day by day,So I add unique key for the offer_id and categories
but the problem is that,when there are the two values containing 
1) offer_id=2 and categories = ecomm
2) offer_id=2 and categories = market

my query will run as follows like

```
REPLACE INTO `affiliate_offer_get_categories_icube` (`offer_id`, `net_provider`, `categories`) VALUES 
(2, 'icube', 'Marketplace'); 

REPLACE INTO `affiliate_offer_get_categories_icube` (`offer_id`, `net_provider`, `categories`) VALUES 
(2, 'icube', 'Ecoommerce');
```

In above statements I have to add two rows of same 'offer_id' but different 'categories'.
but I am getting in result only one row(I have to add values of both categories.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need your unique index to span over both columns. Drop the unique index you have and create a new one with

```
CREATE INDEX idx_whatever_name ON your_tablename (offer_id, categories);
```

Comment: Then I'm afraid I haven't understood your question. Please recreate the problem on http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: I adjusted the sqlfiddle for you with the solution of how I understood your question. Also note, that you don't need a unique key on a primary key. That's almost the same thing. And an index on `(offer_id, categories)` is not the same as having two separate indexes on `offer_id` and ` categories`. See it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cff5/1/0).

Comment: u dont's understand my que.I have to two different categories of the same offer_id

Comment: So? Have you tried it in my sqlfiddle? Doesn't it work? Here's the link again: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cff5/1/0 Please reword your question entirely if I still don't get it.

Comment: @nehaJ Have you tried writing your own insert/replace statements?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92175/discussion-between-nehaj-and-fancypants).

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and desired result. I have a really hard time understanding your problem.